# HttpClient + FileUpload how to download file from servlet to my app?

Tags: java, servlets, file-io, file-upload, multifile-uploader

I have watched the upload snippets which use HttpClient and FileUpload. But I couldn't find any snippet which demo the HttpClient+FileUpload download :( If you know links or even some demo projects share please

Much appreciated useful comments :)

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the web context, you can use a [ServletOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletOutputStream.html). Here resource path info is passed as the extra path info on the HTTP.

```
final ServletOutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();
res.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
String file = req.getPathInfo();
if (file == null) {
  out.println("Extra path info was null; should be a resource to view");
  return;
}

// Convert the resource to a URL
URL url = getServletContext().getResource(file);
if (url == null) { 
  out.println("Resource " + file + " not found");
  return;
}

//Serve the file
InputStream in = url.openStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[4 * 1024]; // 4K buffer
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
  out.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Comment: Is this unlimited file length outputting? And according to the given snippet what client snippet should be then?